# tkinter image sizing with PIL

Tags: image, tkinter, resize, python-imaging-library

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import os

root = Tk()
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("example_image.png"))
panel = Label(root, image = img)
panel.pack(side = "bottom", fill = "both", expand = "yes")
root.mainloop()

root.minsize(width=250, height=275)
root.maxsize(width=375, height=525)
```

I've tried multiple things to work it, but no matter what I try, the image will remain the same size. Just for simplicity's  sake, say the image is 400x800, and I want the image scaled to 125x250, what would i do to modify the above snippet (or redo it) to achieve this not so ambitious goal? Say I have a window that has a min/max size of 250x350/375x525. The image remains the same size but is cut out and the whole of the image cannot be seen, only the portion of the image in the window size can be seen. Is there a way to modify the size of the image without having to change the actual image directly in other software? Thanks in advance, and just ask if I confused you with what I typed.

Comment: why don't you just resize it with PIL? assign this Image.open("example_image.png") to a variable like pimg. then resize that pimg like this: new_pimg = pimg.resize((w,h))

Comment: That's just it, I tried that already and it didn't work.

Comment: Can you show the screen shot of the result with and without the resize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your code improved:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import os


def change_image_size(event):
    # This function resizes original_img every time panel size changes size.
    global original_img
    global img
    global first_run
    global wid_dif
    global hei_dif
    if first_run:
        # Should get size differences of img and panel because panel is always going to a little bigger.
        # You then resize origianl_img to size of panel minus differences.
        wid_dif = event.width - img.width()
        hei_dif = event.height - img.height()
        # Should define minsize, maxsize here if you aren't
        # going to define root.geometry yourself and you want
        # root to fit to the size of panel.
        root.minsize(width=250, height=275)
        root.maxsize(width=375, height=525)
        first_run = False
    pimg = original_img.resize((event.width-wid_dif,event.height-hei_dif))
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(pimg)
    panel.configure(image=img)



first_run = True # first time change_image_size runs
wid_dif = 0 # width difference of panel and first unchanged img
hei_dif = 0 # height difference of panel and first unchanged img

root = Tk()

original_img = Image.open("example_image.png")
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(original_img)
panel = Label(root, image = img)
panel.pack(side = "bottom", fill = "both", expand = "yes")
# This "<Configure>" runs whenever panel changes size or place 
panel.bind("<Configure>",change_image_size)
root.mainloop()
```